# Finding $\phi^{-1}({id_{P(\mathbb{N})}})$, where $\phi:(\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N})\to(P(\mathbb{N})\to P(\mathbb{N}))$ and $\phi(f)(A) = f^{-1}(A)$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, inverse-function

I have function $\varphi : (\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}) \to (P(\mathbb{N}) \to P(\mathbb{N}))$ and  $\varphi(f)(A) = f^{-1}(A)$.
I have to find $\varphi^{-1}({id_{P(\mathbb{N})}})$, and I don't have any idea how to find it.

Any tips?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Let $f\in \phi^{-1}(id_{P(\mathbb N)})$, then by definition for $A\in P(\mathbb N)$, $f$ must satisfies $A\mapsto f^{-1} (A) =A$, in particular what if $A$ is a singleton?

Answer (score 2):

Although it's common in type theory and in some programming languages (such as Haskell) to write the function signature as you have it, the more common way to write it in mathematics is
$$\varphi: \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N} \rightarrow P(\mathbb{N})^{P(\mathbb{N})}$$

where for sets $A, B$, the notation $B^A$ is used to denote the set of all functions $g:A \rightarrow B$.

Regarding your question:

$$\varphi^{-1}(id_{P(\mathbb{N})}) = y $$
where we know that $y \in \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$, so $y : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$. Let's discover some information about $y$. We know that

$$\varphi(y) = \varphi(\varphi^{-1}(id_{P(\mathbb{N})})) = id_{P(\mathbb{N})} \tag 1$$

so we have two pieces of information:

$$\varphi(y)(A) = A \tag 2$$
$$\varphi(y)(A) = y^{-1}(A) \tag 3$$
where (2) follows from (1), and (3) follows from definition of $\varphi$.

Thus,

$$ y^{-1}(A) = A$$

You asked for tips; does this give you enough information for what $y$ could be?

Comment: Ok, so if y−1(A)=A then y(y−1(A))=y(A), so y(A)=A so answer is set of surjective functions?

Comment: Well you're looking just for one function $y : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$, not a set of functions. That is, what is $y(n)$ equal to for $n\in \mathbb{N}$? I can add to the post further if you wish.

Comment: My intuition said that it is $n$, becouse if $A$ is singleton of $n$ then $y(n)$ must be $n$, but I am not sure if I can use this way of thinking.

Comment: Exactly. If $y(n) = n$, then $y = id_\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: But what if I have for example function like that: $f(1) = 2, f(2) = 1$? Then $A = \{1,2\}$ and $f(A) = A$, it is match to our exercises, dont it?

Comment: Yes, but for our statement it is true for all subsets $A \subseteq \mathbb{N}$. For your function $f$, is it true that $f(\{1\}) = \{1\}$?

Comment: Oh, now I understand. Thanks a lot! :) I have another question; 
I am looking for any function $f \in Rg(\varphi)$ which is 1-1. I find example like this:
$g(1) = 1$ then $\varphi(g)(\{1\}) =g^{-1}(\{1\})=f(\{1\})$. Is it a good example?

Comment: You're welcome. Can you elaborate a bit further? You're trying to find an element $f \in ran(\varphi)$ such that $f$ is one-to-one, and you want to know of a procedure toward finding such functions? Is this right? Note that $id_{P(\mathbb{N})} \in ran(\varphi)$, since $\varphi(y) = id_{P(\mathbb{N})}$, so you have at least one already.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take it one step at a time. For any function $g$, what is $g^{-1}(Y)$? It is $g^{-1}(Y)=\{x \mid g(x) \in Y\}$. Now apply that to $\varphi^{-1}(\text{id}_{\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})})$. This set is everything that is mapped by $\varphi$ to $\text{id}_{\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})}$, and here the "everything" means "every function $f:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$" as that is the domain of $\varphi$.

What does it mean for a function $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ to be mapped to the identity function by $\varphi$? It means $\varphi(f)(A)=A$ for every $A\subseteq \mathbb{N}$. I'll leave it to you to determine what functions $f$ satisfy that.